# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error when using has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby, activerecord, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am running into ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error.

I have the following code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => 'users_vendors.db')

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :vendors
end

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I am new to active records in ruby so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you are connecting to the database in this fashion?
The best way to do that is through a database.yml. 
http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/mysql#databaseyml_example

[Edit]
For sqlite: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/sqlite#databaseyml_example

Comment: There is no particular reason. Using a config file of course is better. I added usage of config file, however, that still does not solve my problem. I still get the same error.